# Why is adding a foreign key on the pivot table with different integer types not possible?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Let us assume that we have a products table and a orders table.
The products table have a primary key (tinyint) and the orders table have a primary key (int).

Try adding the foreign key:

```
alter table `products_orders`
add constraint `products_orders_products_id_foreign` foreign key (`products_id`)
references `products` (`id`) on delete cascade;

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Comment: You should include the create table statements, or meaningful abbreviations of them, for both the `products_orders` and `products` tables.  This error could be caused by a handful of things.

Answer (score 1):

Foreign key reference columns data types **must** be exactly the same (including `not null` and `unsigned` flags etc). This avoids any ambiguity when it comes to comparison.

I would recommend that any foreign key columns should be type `Int` and `unsigned`.

Comment: You mean the type of the column on the parent table referenced in the child table must be the same?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean.

Comment: One of the reasons I suspect is that, when the parent id grows bigger, and a reference is needed in the child table, then since the child table holds smaller size column it cannot save the relation thus breaking the possibility of adding the relation.

Comment: Nullability may be different (null is a value, not a type)